# I have a long running lambda function asynchronously invoked by API gateway. How do I return output via same API gateway once execution completes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, asynchronous, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

My function takes about 1-2 min to execute while API gateway has 30 second timeout. To overcome this I followed [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-integration-async.html) and enabled InvocationType:Event header. The issue is that I receive 200 response after execution, but how do I receive my output? I can see lambda output in cloudwatch but what happens to it next?

#### Code used for making request

```js
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhttp.open("POST", "https://my-endpoint.com", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
xhttp.setRequestHeader("InvocationType", "Event");
xhttp.send("foo");

xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      console.log(this.responseText); //no output here
    }
  };
```

If I send a synchronous request by removing InvocationType header then I get desired result.

Answer (score 1):

When dealing to asynchronous functions, you have two ways out:

1. Use a callback url: on your first request, you pass as parameter (or previously configure) a callback url that your function will call when have the result. This is the most efficient way and widely used on many APIs. It's also called web hook
2. Store your lambda function response anywhere and your api client must pool for results. This is not so efficient because you will need to do multiple requests until the lambda function finishes, increasing your costs.

The flow on the first method is like:

- Hey API, do my long duration task, and when ready call me back on `https://sample-domain.com/callback-url`
- API processes the task, and access the given callback url with the result as payload
- The client receives the callback request and processes the result as desired.

There's some security concerns here: someone can discover your callback url and try doing requests to fake something or just trying to DDoS attack.

To mitigate this possibility, you can use random urls for the callback, adding something that identifies the original request.

Comment: I think some changes are needed on the backend side. On inspecting in Chrome developer tools, I don't see any XHR other than the request I made. And that just has a 200 status and no body.